# Rails 3 database design for post model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, database-design

I am building Rails 3 app and  I need some help for my database design. I have model called `Post`. `Posts` also contains `Tutorial`, `Example` and `Comments`.

Comments has own model, but I was wondering should I build own models for `Tutorials` and `Examples`?

Tutorials and examples contains lot of links. Now should I build it like this?

```
Post
has_one :tutorial
has_one :example

Tutorial
belongs_to :post

Example
belongs_to :post
```

Or should I just put tutorial and example fields in `Posts` table? Tutorial and example are shown only when user views post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do `Tutorial` and `Example` have many attributes (and associated logic)? I'd say they should have their own model unless they only have one attribute, in which case a field in the `Post` table would do.

As an aside, if you are able to `Comment` on more than one model consider using a polymorphic association (`Comment` `belongs_to :postable, :polymorphic => true`):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: `Tutorial`and `Example`has only one attribute. And only association is `belongs_to :post`.

Comment: @Oneil In that case (and if you're sure it won't get more complicated later) just add a tutorial and an example field to the `Post` model

Comment: ´Tutorial´and ´Example´ are just text. Only reason for these fields are that I list some links and text. Thank you very much for your help.